# phpmyadmin how to get rid of 2 different login forms

Tags: forms, authentication, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database with 2 users: root and xyz. After installing phpmyadmin I have 2 login forms. At http://localhost/phpmyadmin a first form appears where the user root is denied, but where the user xyz is redirected to another login screen.
[image]

[image]

From that second form both user root and xyz can log in and access the database.
How to get rid of that first login screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with drop user xyz and then create user xyz.
From now I have a single login form (the one with a logo) and both root and xyz can use it for login